# Mapping components to data with nesting

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a way to handle object data from the server, given data I'd like to pass all the data into a thing, and specify one thing and return that thing, for instance if I have a `organization` object and I wanted the `createdAt` date formatted. I would just be able to pass `<data.Organization.createdAt {...organization}>`. Is there anything that does this?

#### Here's the data

```
const contact = {
  name: 'Thomas',
  uuid: 1234
}

const orgnization = {
  contact,
}

const scopedOrgniazation = {
  orgnization
}
```

#### Here's the Components

```
import {RF, SalmonLink} from '../index'

const Contact = {
  Name: ({ name }) => (name) ? <RF>{name}</RF> : <NA/>,
  NameLink: ({ name, uuid }) => (uuid && name) ? <SalmonLink to={`/admin/organizations/${uuid}`}>{name}<SalmonLink> : <NA/>
}

const Organization = {
  Contact
}

const ScopedOrganization = {
  Organization
}
```

#### Desired Components API

I was thinking this may be possible by using something like lodash's `flow` or `flowRight`.

```
<Contact.Name {...contact}>
<Organization.Contact.Name  {...organization}>
<ScopedOrganization.Organization.Contact.Name {...scopedOrgniazation}>
```

Comment: I would also like each level can check if the prop exists just as `name` does for contact.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: you have an object of data, you want a component that takes the object, verify that an attribute within the object exists or not and then return a specific result depending on the attribute existance?

Comment: Yep exactly, that's the idea.